# Parallel sections in OpenMP using a loop

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, sections

I wonder if there is any technique to create parallel sections in OpenMp using a for-loop.

For example, instead of creating n different #pragma omp sections, I want to create them using an n-iteration **for-loop** with some changing parameters for each section.

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
      /* Executes in thread 1 */
   } 
   #pragma omp section
   {
      /* Executes in thread 2 */
   } 
   #pragma omp section
   {
      /* Executes in thread n */
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, look into the `task` directive, available in OpenMP 3.0 and 3.1 (which means that if you use Visual Studio, you are out of luck).

Comment: This answer may also be useful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663750/openmp-for-loop-thread-assignment/13669031

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With explicit OpenMP tasks:

```c
#pragma omp parallel
{
   // Let only one thread create all tasks
   #pragma omp single nowait
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < num_tasks; i++)
          #pragma omp task
          {
              // Code for task with parameters, based on i
          }
   }
   // Let the threads process all tasks
   #pragma omp taskwait

   // Further parallel processing ...
}
```

The code block that follows the OpenMP `task` directive is an explicit task. Explicit tasks are queued an executed later. The `taskwait` directive acts similar to `barrier`, but for tasks. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13789119/1374437) to a similar question.

Tasks can create other tasks recursively. So explicit tasking can be used to process graphs and trees. But beware of the overhead - it is bigger than the overhead from most other constructs and is quite similar to the one that comes from loops with `schedule(dynamic)`. Also the variables from the outer scope, referenced inside the task are by default `firstprivate`.

Note that explicit tasks are feature, that was added in OpenMP 3.0. Compilers that conform to earlier OpenMP versions might not support the `task` directive. Almost all modern compilers do support OpenMP 3.0 or later with the notable exception of Microsoft Visual C++, which only supports OpenMP 2.0 (even in VS2012).

Comment: Does the `nowait` make a difference since there is only one thread creating the tasks?

Comment: It depends - see the other answer I've referred to. Given the sample code here - no. With `nowait` one could put additional code between the `single` constructs and the `taskwait` construct. Without `nowait`, the `taskwait` construct is redundant as the threads will process the tasks while in the implicit barrier.